# JQuery input mask in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, jquery-inputmask

I have an asp:button on my web page. Can I apply JQuery input mask on my asp.net button. Below is what I did:

I installed

```
Install-Package jQuery.InputMask -Version 5.0.2
```

I have this on my page in Head tag:

```
<script src="Scripts/inputmask/inputmask.js"></script>
```

On my web page, I have Phone number field:

<asp:TextBox ID="txtPhonenumber" runat="server" placeholder="(XXX) XXX-XXXX"></asp:TextBox>

I want to apply input mask of phone number on my webform if possible.

Comment: Are you facing any probelm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPhonenumber" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.10/jquery.mask.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#<%= txtPhonenumber.ClientID %>").mask("(999) 9999-9999?9");
            });
  </script>
```

Output here:

[image]